# Are there enough academic jobs for geometric measure theorists?

Tags: mathematics, career-path, job

I am considering focusing on Geometric Measure Theory, and I want to stay in academia.

Some of my colleagues told me that there are fewer and fewer people doing GMT in the US, which would result in fewer and fewer jobs for GM theorists.

**Questions:**

1. Do math departments still hire GM theorists?
2. Is it true that the number of positions is declining?

Comment: I feel like this question could be generalised to "are there enough jobs in academia?". Why do you think geometric measure theorists in particular are having a hard time of it?

Comment: **"_there are fewer and fewer people doing GMT in the US, which would result in fewer and fewer jobs_"**- Did you mean that there are more people doing GMT, such that the job market for GMT's is increasingly saturated?  Or if not, what's the reasoning behind this concern?

Comment: Although it is apparently clear that there are "not enough jobs in academe", some sub-specialties are out of favor, and in that regard this is a very serious question.

Comment: Also, btw,if it is true that fewer-and-fewer people are doing degrees in GMT, that does not _cause_ fewer jobs for that subject... but is perhaps an _effect_...

Comment: Csörnyei was hired as a full professor at the University of Chicago in 2011.

Comment: @Nat I mean fewer people working on GMT will make research on that subject less active so that math departments will hire fewer people specialized in GMT. It's a loop.

Comment: There is less supply and less demand.

Comment: There aren’t enough academic jobs in mathematics in general, as has been discussed in several answers here. My are about GMT specifically though.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about geometric measure theory in particular, and I'm not sure if anyone on this site does. But I can offer one answer to the more general question "Do math departments still hire people working in Specialty X"? In particular, here's one source of information that might help you answer your question:

1. Identify the names of the leading geometric measure theorists in the field, and/or the particular researchers you might be interested in working under.
2. Look them up on the [Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu), and find out the names of students they have graduated in the past 5-10 years.
3. For each student, type in "[Name of Student] Math" into Google; typically, if they are employed in some math department somewhere, either their website or their department's website will be the first hit.

If you know people in the field, you might also ask them directly for their impression of the job market, especially if they or their students were on the job market recently.

Good luck!

Comment: I am worried that, given the significant decline in the number of pure mathematics tenure-track openings from 10 years ago, historical data may not be that accurate.  Very few mathematicians advise so many students that the last 5-10 years of data will be meaningful, especially since the most recent graduates are still doing postdocs.